# Connection Failed: Activation of network connection failed

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet, ipv4

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running on VirtualBox 6.0.4 and I am trying to connect my Xbox one s to the internet via Asix Ethernet adapter. I connected ubuntu to my network but the ethernet connection between ubuntu and my xbox is not working. When I plug in the adapter I get the message Connection Failed: Activation of network connection failed. I need a solution please.

Comment: I'm not extremely computer savvy so I really have no clue about what to do so help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Also, I have now noticed that Ubuntu will not automatically assign the Ethernet from the USB adapter a IPv4 address.